# django-registration login and register on one page

Tags: django, django-registration

Is there a good way to have both the login and register forms for django-registration on one page? I've had trouble finding a way to do it now that the backend system is enforced. Is there a view that can be overwritten that would allow you to add both forms to it? Anyone done this before or can point to an article about this?

Edit: Just to clarify I have the whole django-registration and login system set up and working properly, I'd just like to get both forms on the same page. I do not have access to their views.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just hard-code your login-form in the registration-html-template. It should work like a charm.

Comment: I'd like to avoid doing that, I want to keep this as DRY as possible.

Comment: then include the login template :)

Comment: Does it not rely on the login form being in the context?

Comment: I'm going to mark this as the correct answer. I'd like something more elegant, but as is, I'm just going to hard code the forms and have them post to their respective views.

Comment: thank you. Indeed, it's not elegant - but it's not that ugly and anti-DRY.

Answer (score 0):

You can always override the default login and registration views/templates. You can take a look at this [link](http://devdoodles.wordpress.com/2009/02/16/user-authentication-with-django-registration/) and see if this was what you were thinking to do. Then, you can read the [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/) for further information about making custom login and registration views and templates as well.

Comment: I'm already using django-registration, I'd like to use _it's_ registration form/system and a custom form based on it's login form which uses django's login on one page. Would that be done the same way?

Comment: Yes, because you will use all the Django default login/registration structure and will be able to customize its templates and views for your needs. And by that, I mean you can make your own code using Django patterns, so you won't fall in traps which could ruin the whole framework.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm confused haha. django-registration != django default registration. Has that changed?

Comment: Oh, I wasn't aware that you were talking about an app and not about the Django default registration. Sorry!